# Usage of exit vs return in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have an API built using python running on AWS Lambda. This lambda has a logic to determine if a specific condition is met and proceed with rest of the logic only if the condition is met. In this scenario , should I use exit or return if condition is not met to exit the lambda?

```
    if status != 'PENDING':
       exit()
```

or

```
    if status != 'PENDING':
       return
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739632/lambda-python-exit-code and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780706/stop-a-lambda-function-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use following general syntax structure when creating a handler function in Python:

```
def handler_name(event, context): 
    ...
    return some_value
```

If you don't want to return a value then simply `return` or `return None`. A return value is optional.