# AWS Lambda Handle Error in Python Without Lambda Retrying

Tags: python, aws-lambda

By default if your Lambda function errors it will automatically retry another 2 times. I'm handling certain errors in a Lambda function that aren't really errors, it's basically if the json I'm searching for isn't in the returned json I log that it wasn't found and I would like the script to stop at that point as their isn't anything left for it to do. However as I'm doing try catch exceptions it's logging and exiting correctly but because it reports it as an error Lambda runs it again.

Is it my usage of sys.exit() that is causing it? I don't try/catch errors in the first example but it does retry.

Example: Loop through json nodes, if it finds a match than assign a variable, if it doesn't handle the exception and write to cloudwatch (print) that it didn't find a match.

```
while index < result_nodes:
        if TL2['message_response']['computers'][index]['resource_name'] == instance_name:
            resource_id = TL2['message_response']['computers'][index]['resource_id']
            index += 1

        index += 1
    if resource_id == '':
        print('No match found, quitting.')
        sys.exit()
```

Another similar usage

```
instance_name = ''
    try:
        for tag in response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']:
            if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                instance_name = tag['Value']
        if instance_name == '':
            print('EC2 Instance name not set, quitting')
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print('Step 2 - Get Computer Name: ' + instance_name)
    except Exception:
        print('No tags exist for this terminated EC2 instance, quitting.')
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `sys.exit()` and it shouldn't retry anymore. Similar situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/52739848/12103989

Comment: Good idea, I'll need to refactor a little bit to see if this works as I don't want the rest of the code executing and sys.exit() was my way of stopping it. I'll mark as solution once I confirm.

Comment: @guitarhero23 You can use return or callback statement if you don't want the rest of the code executing.